# ColdFusion - local server not using CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion-administrator

I can load all of the pages in my local folder using localhost:8500/domain/pagename.cfm but it all loads as plain text and pictures. None of the CSS formatting is present - I'm mainly using Bootstrap 3.

I'm wondering if there's something in the ColdFusion Administrator (version 10) that I need to set up differently?

Everything looks great in the live view.

Comment: Did you try with sample html page as basic sanity check?

Comment: Just did. Other ColdFusion sites work correctly (for the most part). I guess it's just a Bootstrap issue.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, open up the Developer Tools and check the Network tab for the 404 to see where it's trying to load the file. You've most likely got an incorrect path to the CSS file from the point of view of the website's root.

Comment: The internal web server is case sensitive, even if it is running on Windows. You may want to check that

Comment: Yup. That's the issue. Because I have multiple domains in my wwwroot folder, I have to define the domain in the URL (localhost:8500/domain/pagename.cfm). The local page is trying to pull the CSS from localhost:8500/css/bootstrap.css (without the domain specification). Is there any way around that? Or do I need to restructure my files anytime I want to locally test a CF site?

Comment: You could do something like <cfif cgi.server_name is not "localhost"><cfset bfold=""><cfelse><cfset bfold="/domain.com"></cfif> and then reference like <link href="#bfold#/path/mystyles.css"...>

You could probably also use html's BASE tag to get this done, but it still needs a similar if statement.

Just one option, of course you could structure differently.